# What does $|u|=2|v|$ mean (in $\{(u\#,v\#): u, v \in \{a,b\}^*, |u|=2|v|\}$)?

Tags: formal-languages

I want to know what $|u|=2|v|$ means in $$\{(u\#,v\#): u, v \in \{a,b\}^*, |u|=2|v|\}$$ I'm not familiar with this notation.

I also want to understand what these mean:
$$\{(a^mb^n\#,a^kb^n\#): n,m,k \ge 0\}$$
$$\{(a^nb^m\#,a^kb^n\#): n,m,k \ge 0\}$$

The # signs are used to denote a end of string in Automata, aka a single # at the end of the string.

Comment: What is box?  What specific set?  |X| = 2|X| means the cardinality of X is twice the cardinality of X.  What the other means I have no idea.  Include some context and write clearer.

Comment: My browser does not render 24 of the characters in this post, so it is impossible to read.

Comment: "U+1D462 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL U" is not universally available. Fortunately, you can use MathJax here, to avoid having to deal with obscure Unicode characters,

Comment: I think this post, now clarified by rici, should be reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda hard to understand this question without knowing the specific context. But I'm guessing $u$ and $v$ are words in the alphabet $\{a,b\}$, and then $|u|$ and $|v|$ stand for their respective lengths. So $|u|=2|v|$ means that the length of the word $u$ is twice the length of the word $v$.

Also, things like $a^m$ represent words where the letter $a$ is repeated $m$ times. For example, $a^5=aaaaa$. If $m$ runs over all non-negative integers, then $a^m$ runs over all words (including the empty one, when $m=0$) consisting of the letter $a$ only. You can similarly interpret expressions such as $a^mb^n$.

(Disclaimer: I don't know what the "$\#$" stands for…)

Comment: (I suspect $\#$ is just an extra symbol, different from $a$ and $b$.)

Comment: Yes, using # as a symbol is quite standard in formal languages.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Thank you! I didn't know that.